# Preprocessing of own handwritten numbers in machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

Denoising Autoencoder was created to remove noise from noisy handwritten numbers.

Next, I would like to input noisy handwritten numbers that I have prepared myself into the model I created and remove the noise. I have written code to do this, but it does not generate any errors and does not display the image after noise removal.

The following Denoising Autoencoder was created to remove noise from noisy handwritten numbers.

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras import layers
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))

noise_factor = 0.5
x_train_noisy = x_train + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_train.shape) 
x_test_noisy = x_test + noise_factor * np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=x_test.shape) 

x_train_noisy = np.clip(x_train_noisy, 0., 1.)
x_test_noisy = np.clip(x_test_noisy, 0., 1.)

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train,
                epochs=25,
                batch_size=128,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test_noisy, x_test),
                callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/tb', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False)])
autoencoder.save("model_number.h5")
```

Next, I want to input the noisy handwritten number "noise_number1.png" that I have prepared myself, into the created model to remove the noise. I wrote the following code for this purpose, but no error occurs and the denoised image is not displayed. How can I solve this problem? Specific code would be helpful.

```py
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import load_model

img = Image.open('/content/noise_number1.png').convert('L')
img=img.resize((28,28)) 
img = np.array(img) 
img=img.reshape(28,28,1)
autoencoder=load_model("model_number.h5")
pred = autoencoder.predict(img[np.newaxis])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not plotting the denoised image to display.

```
from PIL import Image
from keras.models import load_model

img = Image.open('/content/img_3.jpeg').convert('L')
img=img.resize((28,28))
img = np.array(img)
img = img / 255.0. # rescale the image
img=img.reshape(28,28,1)

autoencoder=load_model("model_number.h5")
pred_new = autoencoder.predict(img[np.newaxis])
```

Please use below code for displaying the image along with other part of code:

```
#To display original image
plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(img))
```

[image]

```
#To display denoised image
plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(pred_new))
```

[image]